# limit on focal length of converging lens

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses

Realistically, is there any sort of limit on the focal length of a converging lens? Typically I see focal lengths of at least a couple centimeters. I am looking for a lens with less than 1 cm focal length. Is this possible?

Comment: -1. No research effort. Have you tried looking for such a lens in the online catalog of an optics distributor? eg Edmund Optics, ThorLabs.

Comment: If asking about camera lenses, try [Lensora](http://www.lensora.com/list_lenses.asp?sel=zoom_min).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit is probably a ball lens, when the incoming beam is the full diameter of the ball then the focal point is on the surface. It is easy make ball lenses with a diameter (and so EFL) < 1mm

[image]

In practice it is generally trickier to make a very long focal length single lens, it is is much easier to make a ball than an almost flat convex lens.

Comment: Interesting. This is what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

The focal length of any lens can be reduced by shrinking the lens in all dimensions. So short focal lengths of 1mm or 2mm are achievable. However, they will have correspondingly small diameters, so they collect much less light. Area scales as $f^2$ so a lens with $\frac{1}{10}$ the focal length of another lens of a similar shape will collect only $\frac{1}{100}$ as much light.

Answer (score 1):

[For £7 you can buy a ball lens with a focal length of $0.345\,\rm mm$.](http://www.comaroptics.com/components/lenses/simple-convex-lenses/sapphire-and-glass-ball-lenses)

The focal length (centre of sphere to focal point distance) $f$ of a ball lens is given by the [equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345268/how-is-the-formula-for-the-focal-point-of-a-ball-lens-derived) $f=\dfrac{nR}{2(n-1)}$ where $R$ is the radius of the ball (sphere) and $n$ the refractive index of the material of which the lens is made.

So for a given material $f\propto R$, decreasing the radius of the ball decreases the focal length.
Using sapphire $(n=1.765)$ rather than glass $(n\approx 1.5)$ has the advantage of a smaller focal length for a given radius of ball and also reducing spherical aberration.

Making the radius smaller does reduce the physical size of the lens and hence its light gathering capacity.

Ball lenses were the basis of [Leeuwenhoek's microscopes](http://www.funsci.com/fun3_en/usph/usph.htm) and have recently recently come into fashion with the advent of [smartphone microscopy](http://www.instructables.com/id/10-Smartphone-to-digital-microscope-conversion/).